# How to make a directory act as root on a server?

Tags: c++, linux, http, document-root

I'm writing a server that outputs its directory contents to the client on a GET  request.

How would I implement a parameter argv[2] to specify a root directory for all clients so that when a client requests `"GET /"` or `"GET /file"` the server will view it as the root directory?

For example:

`./TCPserver 5000 /home/user`

then client side:

`./TCPclient localhost 5000 "GET /"`

`./TCPclient localhost 5000 "GET /(fileinHome)"`

Here is what I have but obviously this does not cover the case that the client tries to access a file in the pseudo root directory

```
        if (strcmp(real_path, "/")) 
            {
                DIR *dirp = opendir(argv2);
                if (dirp == 0) 
                {   //dup sock into stderr
                close(2);
                dup(clientSocket);
                perror(real_path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            struct dirent *dirEntry;
            while ((dirEntry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) 
            {
            if (dirEntry->d_name[0] != '.')
            {
                strcpy(buffer, dirEntry->d_name);
            }
            } //end while

            closedir(dirp);

            } //end if
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `chroot()` — which is not part of POSIX or the SUS (Single Unix Specification)? Or [BSD jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail)?  Be cautious...

Comment: Maybe just [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html)?

Comment: do you want to change the default directory for your apache server to some other directory than default i.e /var/www ?

Comment: If you used `chdir()`, you'd also have to remove the leading slash(es) from any pathnames that were specified, as well as leading `../` nonsense (or embedded `../../../../` nonsense).

Comment: To add to the previous comment, don't forget about symlinks in the fake root pointing outside of it either.